# What does the "growing angle of a curve" actually mean?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

At several parts on [this](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/83693) thesis the author mentions the "growing angle" of curves ("limiting growing angle", "limiting growing angle of two ends of a curve"). What does that really mean?

[image]

The author also mentions "limiting growing direction" in [another very similar article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1007.1617.pdf), and I can't figure out what that means either. I'd appreciate any help on clarifying these therms and how the author computes these angles.

*Update*: Apparently this is called the polar tangential angle. I'll look further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed the polar tangential angle.